# How to bind data in asp.net c# treeview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have never used treeview control in asp.net but now I need to bind data to it. My stored procedure from sql server is returning the the values as below. I m using c#

```
TermID  ParentID  Name
2021    0          A. Geographic locations
3602    2021       Oceania
3604    3602       Australasia
3621    3604       New Zealand
3619    3604       Pacific Islands
3585    3619       Polynesia
3592    3585       Samoa
3594    3592       American Samoa
```

Each Term has parentID and any TermID with ParentID=0 is the root node. How can we bind this data to treeview. I will appreciate any advise or examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be useful :

TreeView control expects a heirarchical data structure like xml/sitemaps, so we cant bind the DataTable to it directly. Use data table Select where ParentID = ID

Please use a recursive method to create child items relevent to current menu item ID, refer to link below for code.

http://www.charith.gunasekara.web-sphere.co.uk/2010/10/how-to-bind-datatable-to-aspnet.html

n below link will help you creating ur own tree view control.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/DataBoundTreeView.aspx